# How does one convert seconds (or milliseconds) to a timestamp (or just a string that looks like a date) in mySql

Tags: mysql

I'm looking at this documentation
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime
And I KNOW I must be missing it, but I just don't see a function here that I can pass seconds (or milliseconds) to, and get back either a Timestamp, or just a string representing the date.

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are working with seconds since 1970 (i.e. Unix timestamps then [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)) could well be what you want.

`FROM_UNIXTIME` Returns a representation of the `unix_timestamp` argument as a value in 
`'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format, depending on whether the function is
used in a string or numeric context.
The value is expressed in the current time zone. `unix_timestamp` is an internal timestamp value such as is produced by the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).  That converts the number of seconds since midnight Jaunuary 1, 1970 into a timestamp.

If you have the time in seconds since midnight of your current day, then use the [MAKETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime) function.

```
MAKETIME( seconds / (60*60),
          seconds / 60,
          seconds % 60 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

> STR_TO_DATE('Dec/15/2008', '%M/%d/%Y'); => 2008-12-15
>
> STR_TO_DATE('31/Jan/2008', '%d/%M/%Y'); => 2008-01-31
>
> STR_TO_DATE( '31/Jan/2008 23:52', '%d/%M/%Y %H:%i' ) => 2008-01-31 23:52:00

Answer (score 0):

First off, what do you mean by passing seconds to retrieve a timestamp? Aren't the seconds the timestamp already?

Secondly, you are looking for this function if you want to do this in SQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Thirdly, you may want to consider just retrieving the timestamp from the database, and letting the application (e.g., in PHP, I don't know which language you're using) turn it into the required format. If you're consistent in this design it allows you to more generically define your date formats.

Comment: You're not understanding my question. So, no, seconds aren't timestamps (they're seconds), the method you pointed me takes a date (not seconds) which is precisely what I'm trying to GET, but don't have, and to your third point, that IS my question... how do I get a timestamp from the database, when the database field is just stored as raw seconds.

Comment: 1) UNIX timestamps are in seconds, so I don't see the difference. Be more clear. 2) You're right, I'm sorry, 3) that is not your question, you're asking how to get the SQL query to reformat the data, I'm suggesting you just get the raw value from the database and reformat it to your wishes in your application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying (and I got my answer, so, I'm just commenting to be polite). I appreciate you offering help, but I'm not sure how my question is unclear. I said I'm looking to pass seconds into a method that gives me back a timestamp (or some proximity thereof).  How could I be clearer?