# How to convert seconds into "DD:HH:MM" format

Tags: mysql

I tried to use `SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)` and worked and gave result as below

```
SEC_TO_TIME(161295.38237498334)
```

result:

```
44:48:15.382375
```

I need to get result in (DD:HH:MM)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Comment: If you're using seconds since 1970 (Unix timestamps), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385349/how-does-one-convert-seconds-or-milliseconds-to-a-timestamp-or-just-a-string

Answer (score 3):

If you're using UNIX timestamps as [@Mark Leiber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295751/how-to-covert-seconds-into-ddhhmm-format-in-mysql#comment48687982_30295751) mentions, then take a look at [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

If you are NOT using timestamps, but instead want to format an arbitrary time value, then you could look at the [`TIME_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(161295.38237498334), '%H:%i:%s')
```

Unfortunately `TIME_FORMAT` can only represent the hours and minutes portion. To get the number of days you could use:

```
FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(161295.38237498334)) / 24)
```

then format the remaining hours and minutes:

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(161295.38237498334 % (24 * 60 * 60)), '%H:%i'))
```

You can then put it altogether using `CONCAT()`. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68deb/12) for a complete working example.

---

You can refer to the whole list of MySQL time and date functions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

See also [@RichardTheKiwi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533882) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279079/mysql-convert-timediff-output-to-day-hour-minute-second-format) related question.