# MySQL convert seconds to datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, seconds

So I have an integer '63605914755' like this:

```
SELECT TO_SECONDS( '2015-08-04 13:40:56' )
-----
Result: '63605914755'
```

How do I convert '63605914755' back from seconds to datetime (Ex: '2015-08-04 13:40:56') ?

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385349/how-does-one-convert-seconds-or-milliseconds-to-a-timestamp-or-just-a-string - please read this.

Comment: I've read it but it didn't solve my problem. That's why I made this. 
Both UNIX_TIMESTAMP(63605914755) and FROM_UNIXTIME(63605914755) return NULL.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp  I would suggest using this - then hopefully it will work.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(seconds - to_seconds('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) as my_date_time
FROM 
  your_table
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58dad/3)

Comment: '63605914755' is seconds, it is NOT a UNIX TIMESTAMP.
Your solution returned NULL.

Comment: Be wary if your MySQL server has a timezone offset, this will cause the results of `FROM_UNIXTIME` to be off. The [timezone MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) uses by default is `SYSTEM`, but can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to simply add the number of seconds back to the base date of `0000-01-00`. However, using `0000-01-00` will result in `NULL` so we have to specify the first day of the month `0000-01-01`.
This results in the date being off by 1 day. To account for this we just subtract 1 day from the resulting date:

### Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/YNJ7Q856

```
SELECT '0000-01-01' + INTERVAL TO_SECONDS('2015-08-04 13:40:56') SECOND - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Results:

```
2015-08-04 13:40:56
```

---

To create a `FROM_SECONDS` function use:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `FROM_SECONDS`(
    `secs` BIGINT
)
RETURNS DATETIME
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    RETURN '0000-01-01' + INTERVAL secs SECOND - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
END//
```

```
SELECT FROM_SECONDS(TO_SECONDS('2015-08-04 13:40:46'));
```

*As `DATETIME` values are points in time references (static), the above query can be `DETERMINISTIC`, since the resulting values of the supplied seconds will always be the same.*

---

**Note:**
Since the the Unix Epoch date is based on UTC, when your MySQL server uses a timezone with an offset, using `FROM_UNIXTIME(seconds - seconds_from_epoch)`, the resulting datetime will be off by that offset. The [default timezone used by MySQL is the `SYSTEM` timezone](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).
For EST using `FROM_UNIXTIME` will result in `2015-08-04 09:40:56`.

To account for this issue, you need to calculate the difference in minutes between `UTC_TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_TIME` and subtract the resulting minute offset from `FROM_UNIXTIME`. This will have no effect if your server uses `UTC` since the resulting offset will be 0.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(TO_SECONDS('2015-08-04 13:40:56') - TO_SECONDS('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) - INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NOW()) MINUTE;
```

Result:

```
2015-08-04 13:40:56
```

Comment: Darn, this is ugly but correct, and the unit time limitations do not restrict it. It is annoying that MySQL has an incomplete set of functions. It offers to_seconds, which is a great function, but it does not offer the reverse function. This is by no means the only example where MySQL is functionally incomplete.